# find elements by classname

Tags: javascript, class, find, element

i have the following question:

in my body i hav this div construction:

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page">
        <div id="page-content" class="page-inner">
            <div id="page-content-inner">
                <div class="box tagcloud">
                    <div class="modulcontent">
                        <div class="tagspopular tagcloud tagscloud tagcloud">
                            <span class="tag" >
                                <a class="tag-name" > test1</a>
                            </span>
                            <span class="tag">
                                <a class="tag-name" >test2</a>
                            </span>
                            <span class="tag">
                                <a class="tag-name" >test3</a>
                            </span>
                            <span class="tag">
                                <a class="tag-name" > test4</a>
                            </span>
                            <span class="tag">
                                <a class="tag-name" >test5</a>
                            </span>
                            <span class="tag">
                                <a class="tag-name" >test6</a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know want to select the spans with the "tag"-class with javascript.

I first tried normal javascript:

```
var elementArray;

elementArray = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");

for(var i = 0; i < elementArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(elementArray[i].className);
}
```

But there is nothing in the protocol
http://jsfiddle.net/42RJD/2/

Then i tried with jquery:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-migrate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var pre = $('.tag');

    pre.each(function(i, el){
        console.log( el );
        // OR
        console.log( this ); // will give you the element

        // suppose to get text
        console.log( $(el).text() ); // or $(this).text()
    });
</script>
```

When i tried this, i got a Error: `TypeError: $ is not a function var pre = $('.tag');`

http://jsfiddle.net/42RJD/3/

I actual don't know what to do. I get both codes from here but it still dont work. :(

Comment: Well you are running it in no conflict mode so you should be using `jQuery('.tag')` that is even if the libraries are loading.

Comment: You don't need noconflict under normal circumstances. Remove `jquery-noconflict.js` if you don't need noconflict (or you don't know what that means).

Comment: What is not working with your non jQuery example?

Comment: The console stays empty, it doesn't detect the tag-elements

Comment: @epascarello: i changed the $('.tag') into jQuery('.tag'). Now i got no error, but console still is empty :(

Comment: You've got a syntax error in your first fiddle. Check out http://jsfiddle.net/42RJD/4/

Comment: maybe, i using jsfiddle the first time, maybe i got something wrong. i copypasted the whole part of the code. on my code i dont get a syntax error. Could you say me which line you mean?

Comment: Code seems to run fine in the fiddle.

Comment: Ok i found the syntax error. Thanks. But doesnt solve the problem. :(

Comment: @epascarello  how can i check the console output in fiddle?

Comment: open up the console...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `.ready()` to execute the code when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var pre = $('.tag');

    pre.each(function(i, el){
        console.log( el );
        // OR
        console.log( this ); // will give you the element

        // suppose to get text
        console.log( $(el).text() ); // or $(this).text()
    });

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Thank you very much. The $commands also dont worked. I now changed all $ into  jQuery and now i get what i want. Thank you very much. And also thanks all others for help!

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer was useful, please mark it as right.